# transition not working when focus/unfocus

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMrqpr), the 3 seconds transistion is working fine.

but [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxvRVP), no transition at all. When I focus, the label will go top right away, same as when unfocus, it will go down right away:

```
span {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -30px;
  display: block;
  padding: .6em 0;
  padding-left: -5px;
  transition: top 3s ease 
}

input:focus + label > span {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 16px; 
}
```

Comment: what is your desired result ? how the label and its after pseudo element should be placed when the input is focused ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `span` does not have a default `top` value.

You need to add `top:0` to your CSS.

```
span {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -30px;
  display: block;
  padding: .6em 0;
  padding-left: -5px;
  transition: top 3s ease/*, font-size .5s ease*/; 
 /* transition: transform 1s 2s;*/
  top:0;
}
```